# validates record on modal popup asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a project where I have Dropdownlist and add button to  open a modal in the modal I have a textbox and a button  to add the records in the table 
value is inserting in the DB, after inserting modal popup close, now I want to validate the duplicate records if the record is already in the database it shows already inserted if it is not there then insert the record and close the popup modal. what is happening now is when I click submit it validates but it closes the modal popup and when I again open the popup the error is visible there I am sharing the screenshot and the code please guide me if anyone has an idea on that [image] on the first image I click on add button then  modal pops up  like the second image
[image]

Now I want the validation on the modal to check on submit button  if the record already exists in DB without closing the modal popup

Here is my code.

```
    <div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <label>Region</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" class="form-control" 
        AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                         </div>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbaddRegion" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-region"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style ="font-size:18px; padding:4px;"></span></asp:LinkButton>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-region" Visible="False"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style ="font-size:18px"></span></asp:LinkButton>

                                </div>

    <div class="modal fade in" id="modal-region" >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Setup Region</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Enter Region Name</p><asp:Label ID="lblRegionError" runat="server" Text=" (Region Already exist)" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRegion" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitRegion" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSubmitRegion_Click"/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be really great, if you could share your code with us.

Comment: @Marco  I have shared the code please have a look, and guide me if you have any idea on that

Comment: This happens because of the postback behavior. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52103270/7324631)